# A new activity on top of third party app in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

My application(A) open another 3rd party application(B) installed in my device. Now, I made a transparent activity(C) which I want open on top of (B) to keep screen awake and show some other information. Meanwhile I want to keep running both B and C activity.

These are functions. C(KeepAwake) Activity is only open while I close the B.

```
private void launchActivity(String PacakageName){
        Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(PacakageName);
        startActivityForResult(launchIntent,GPLUS);
    }



@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode){
            case GPLUS:
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,KeepAwake.class);
                startActivity(in);
        }
    }
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I saw an app like that

Comment: In that case activity B would be in paused state? What did you mean my running? Just visible?

Comment: Visible and Running.

Comment: "How can I solve my problem?" -- what is the "problem"? Also, please explain, **completely and precisely**, what "keep running" means.